# CSS Overflow-y issue in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

IE 11 is not playing ball with the overflow-y on my site.

http://mdsrecipes.azurewebsites.net/

If click on the Chicken with Leeks and Mushrooms recipe in Chrome.
The recipe details scrolls nicely in the div.

But in IE it does not work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks
Malcolm

Comment: I keep trying but I give up since the structure is not right in the first place, tables are use to present tabular data as much as possible, use divs next time

Comment: I do not know what you mean. The question as all the information necessary to answer it.

Comment: It has been a while since I used SO. So if there is a new protocol for asking questions I apologize.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it __in the question itself__. Questions without __a clear problem statement__ are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: My question is simple as it can get and it includes everything you need to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Changes required in your **css**

```
#reciperightcolumn{
overflow:hidden
}
#divrecipe{
 height:600px;  /*make it as 600px instead of 100% */
 overflow-y:auto;
```

}

Comment: I don't want the height set to a fixed height as obviously I want it to work on different screen sizes. But thanks for the try.